# How to add to a select element using XMLhttpRequest with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I want to retrieve the values in mysql database via PHP, and I want to dynamically add them as choices inside a select element.

This is my html code:

```
<label for='listDivision'>Division</label><select id='listDivision' name='listDivision' disabled='true' onchange='getList(this, "getDepartments");'>
                    <!-- list of divisions in here -->  

                    </select>
```

And this is the javascript code which retrieves the response text code:

```
                switch(val.id)
                {
                    case "listCompany":
                    var div = document.getElementById("listDivision");
                    alert(ajaxRequest.responseText);
                    break;
                }
```

And this is my php code:

```
function getDivisions()
{   
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_division";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<option value='".$row['Division_ID']."'>".$row['Division_Name']."</option>";
    }
}
```

However, the php echo does not add it into the select. Any other way I can do this?

Comment: Your functions are not matching. In your HTML, you are using `getList(this, "getDepartments");` but the JS you provided is using a function called `getDivisions()`.

Comment: Actually, the getDivisions() in the php code are being called as a result of the ajaxRequest.open. It works when I alert the ajaxRequest.responseText. I just needed to know how to add the result of the echo inside the <select> element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm. I have already fixed it.

I just generated the entire select code inside the php that it calls.